# Getting the value of a SettingKey[T]

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm working on a plugin for document generation. I'd like to output all generated files to a directory of my choosing. This directory, can be a subdirectory of SBT's `target` directory, as follows:

```
val newTargetDirectory = SettingKey[File]("document-target-dir")
newTargetDirectory <<= target( _ / "new_output_folder")
```

If I cannot 'create' a `File` object from this new setting, how do I utilise it?

Comment: It seems like you're going about whatever it is you're trying to do in not quite the right way, as @RM. said.  You might try adding some more information to your question about what you're trying to accomplish.  For example, when do you want this to happen?  Do you want it to happen on every compile or only when you're packaging?

Comment: use .value method

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ordinarily, you don't "get the value of a setting", you make another setting or a task depend on your setting, which causes the configuration system to provide that other thing with the value at the appropriate time.  The sections of the SBT wiki on ["more about settings"](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/More-About-Settings) and ["custom settings and tasks"](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Custom-Settings.html) have a great deal of detail and many simple examples on this, especially the "Settings with dependencies" and "Tasks with dependencies" sections in the "more about" page.

Comment: Modified question to help understanding.

Comment: With more reading, understanding and tinkering, you're answer makes sense.I also found the [Tasks with inputs](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Tasks) section useful.