# How do I evaluate an sbt SettingsKey

Tags: sbt

I want to combine the [sbt-release](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release) plugin with the Play framework.

The plugins reads the current version number from a file `version.sbt`. Its content is

```
version in ThisBuild := "0.41.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

I would like to use this setting in my main build file but the variable `version` is of type [`sbt.SettingKey`](http://harrah.github.io/xsbt/latest/api/sbt/SettingKey.html).

There is an `evaluate` method but for the life of me I can't figure out what to pass in to get the String I defined in `version.sbt`.

Comment: how do you want to use it in your build file? To use its value to define some other setting or task?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989285/getting-the-value-of-a-settingkeyt

Comment: I want the release plugin's version to be the version of the play.Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little shortcoming with the `play.Project` constructor, it excepts a static version number, not one from a setting key.

However, the only required parameter is the application name, so you can switch from something like:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, settings = 
  Defaults.defaultSettings ++ releaseSettings ).settings(...)
```

to

```
val main = play.Project(appName).settings(appDependencies).
  settings(releaseSettings).settings(...)
```

Normally, the version defined in `version.sbt` should be picked up here automagically. If it isn't, you can always add to the above:

```
.settings(applicationVersion <<= version in ThisBuild)
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried the accepted answer's solution but it didn't compile. (Play 2.1.5)

```
[error]   (ss: sbt.Project.Setting[_]*)sbt.Project <and>
[error]   => Seq[sbt.Project.Setting[_]]
[error]  cannot be applied to (Seq[sbt.ModuleID])
[error]   val main = play.Project(appName).settings(appDependencies).settings(releaseSettings).settings(
[error]                                    ^
[error] one error found
```

Instead I came up with this solution:

```
    ...
    lazy val appSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ ... ++ releaseSettings

    val main = play.Project(appName, dependencies = appDependencies, settings = appSettings).settings(
      version <<= version in ThisBuild,
      ...
    )
```